# Which type of components required to achieve pre-determined output sequence?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

Just getting back into electronics. I would like to create a circuit that can be programmed to control the state of a light bulb / relay - e.g., on for 2 seconds, off for 12 seconds, on for 5 seconds, off for 1 second, etc.

Don't really know where to start with this particular project, so not even sure what to search for.

Hoping someone might be able to push me in the right direction.

Comment: How accurate can the timing be? What about using 16 timeslots which define the boundaries over a 20 second period?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [555 Timer delay vs. Delay IC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/276727/555-timer-delay-vs-delay-ic)

Comment: Things like this are done best with a micro-controller. Anything else will be more complicated (at least electronically).For a relative noob, an Arduino might be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Arduino looks perfect.